# React Deployment to Firebase from Gitlab fails with error: to Specified public directory 'build' does not exist, can't deploy hosting to site

Tags: reactjs, firebase, gitlab-ci, firebase-hosting

This is the firebase.json file

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: tragopoulos/firebase:latest

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REPO"

build:
  stage: build
  image: node
  script:
    - echo "# Start building App"
    - npm install
    - npm build
    - echo "# Build successfully!"
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
      - "/build"
      - node_modules/

test:
  stage: test
  image: node
  script:
    - echo "# Testing App"
    - npm install
    - CI=true npm test
    - echo "# Test successfully!"

deploy-develop:
  stage: deploy
  environment: tragopoulos-portfolio-dev
  only:
    - develop
  before_script:
    - npm install
    - npm build
  script:
    - echo "# Deploying App"
    - firebase use tragopoulos-portfolio --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
    - firebase deploy --only hosting -m "Pipeline $CI_PIPELINE_ID Build $CI_BUILD_ID"
    - echo "# Deployed successfully!"
```

and this is the error:

[image]

I tried "build", "/build", "/build/", "/PROJECT_NAME/build" nothing is working. I also don't know how to `$ echo` the build path so I can debug it in the project. In Angular the "dist" works without any issue. Any idea?

Comment: It's a silly question from me but does the `build` folder exist once deploying? I have the same setup as `"public": "build"` and it works like charm. Before the deploy I run `npm run build` just to be sure.

Comment: @norbitrial I added the `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Maybe you can see the issue there. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Probably I would try to combine `before_script` and `script` first. Add install and build steps into `script` before the deployment and see how that goes. Maybe these steps are running in different containers (not really familiar with **gitlab-ci**, just a guess) and the build folder is not visible for the deployment step.

Comment: You are using `npm build` which you probably want to be `npm run build` as [npm build](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/build) is for building a node package, not CRAs build command.

Comment: @norbitrial, feel free to add your comment as an answer so I can solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the conversation on the comment section, it seems there is no `build` folder created in the deployment step. Most probably they are running in different containers. Thus the `firebase deploy` command does not find the necessary `build` one.

I would try to remove `before_script` from `.gitlab-ci.yml` and combine its steps with `script` as:

```
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm build
    - echo "# Deploying App"
    - firebase use tragopoulos-portfolio --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
    - firebase deploy --only hosting -m "Pipeline $CI_PIPELINE_ID Build $CI_BUILD_ID"
    - echo "# Deployed successfully!"
```

This way you have the `build` folder in place for the deployment step.